# Why is this subquery valid?

Tags: sql, database

I have a table looking similar to this

[image]

I needed a query that brings back the person who has more than the average salary in their branch. In order to achieve this, I wrote a query as below

```
select * from 
workers a 
where SAL > (select avg(sal) from workers b 
where a.branch_no = b.branch_no)
```

Somehow this worked and gave me

[image]

I thought this will give me an error since I reckoned the subquery will return three rows i.e. average salary for branch 10, 20, and 30.
Can anyone explain what actually happened with my subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery is an aggregation query.

An aggregation with no `group by` *always* returns exactly one row.  The one row has the average salary for workers in the same branch (as the worker in the outer query).

Comment: So, do you mean it will return the average salary for each branch in a single row, i.e. group by branchid in a single row?

Comment: @Coder . . . For each row in the outer query, the subquery calculates average for the branch.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery is an aggregation query without a `group by` clause. Such query is guaranteed to always return one row.

Another thing to keep in mind is that this is a *correlated* subquery. The `where` clause filters the dataset for the rows where `branch_no` is equal to to the value on the current row in the outer query. Even if it had a `group by` clause on the branch, it would still return one row only.

Note that you can express the same logic with window functions, if your database supports them (pre-8.0 versions of MySQL are a notable exception):

```
select *
from (
    select w.*, avg(sal) over(partition by branch_no) as avg_sal
    from workers w
) w
where sal > avg_sal
```